# Change application files at runtime

Tags: android

In my application I have some configuration information stored in `xml` file, which I want to update lately at run-time and store new configuration `xml` file. But I cannot save them under `res` directory or in `assets` and what is best practice to do with such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Download and save the file to internal storage (e.g., `getFilesDir()`, called on your `Activity` or other `Context`). For reading, use the file on internal storage if it exists, otherwise fall back to using the one that you packaged with your app.

Comment: in this case can user modify the file?

Comment: @pepela: Presumably you will let the user modify the file through your app. Most users will not have access to this file outside of your app. The exception will be users of rooted devices, as they can elect to get at any file they want within their devices.

Answer (score 0):

1) why do not you use the built-in `SharedPreferences`? That would be the best practice.

By the way, Android already does initialize settings with some xml: search for "android preferences xml" and see results, e.g. http://rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/

2) you can store it in assets/ or raw/, but you will have to unpack the file yourself

To print the list of assets:

```
    String[] assets = getAssets().list(subdir);
    {
        String list = subdir + " files:";
        for (String asset: assets) {
            list += " ";
            list += asset;
        }
        list += " (total "+assets.length+")";
        Log.d(DEBUGTAG,list);
    }
```

Comment: files are many and sometimes they can grow in count, cannot use `SharedPreferences` for that, and as I read files in assets/ and raw/ are read only and can't be changed at runtime